# How do I Uniquely identify a column from information_schema in mysql or postgresql?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, information-schema

I am looking into keeping tab of columns and changes made on a database and its tables. Want to check whether a column has changed, e.g. data type or numeric precision has changed.

Have checked on COLUMNS table but no way of uniquely identify a column. i.e. there's no column there that can be equated to a primary key.

How can I query the information schema to identify a column for earmarking and check if changes are made to it?

Comment: First of all, is it postgress or mysql? Can't be both. Secondly the COLUMNS table include the database and table as well as the column name, so they can be identified uniquely. If you want to know which column is the primary key, or a unique key, that would take a little more work.

Comment: For either, I believe they share common column names in the information_schema.COLUMNS table. and am looking into working with both.

Answer (score 1):

## About `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`

[`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema) is defined by the SQL standard. So, if properly implemented, it should be consistant across databases ([Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/information-schema.html), [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html), etc.).

On the `COLUMNS` tables, the following four fields together will uniquely identify each column-entity.

- `TABLE_CATALOG`
- `TABLE_SCHEMA`
- `TABLE_NAME`
- `COLUMN_NAME`

The **`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is a veneer overlaying the databases’ actual table**s used for tracking meta-data. You may be able to get more detailed Information about that meta-data by querying directly these natively-defined tables. For example, in Postgres, see the [system catalogs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs.html). Of course, that means you must research and write queries separately for each database implementation (Postgres, MySQL, etc.).

Note that some database systems support `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and some do not. See that Wikipedia page for a list.

## Active monitoring

As for monitoring changes to this meta-data, I do not know of any standard way to do this.

I suspect actively monitoring for additions, updates, and deletions to this meta-data will require you to write code specific to each database system.

Two ideas come to mind, but neither is standard:

- Query the native underlying counterparts for their unique identifier column values, collect these IDs, persist the current state of the tables and columns you care about. Then periodically query on those IDs to compare to your persisted data to see what matches and what has changed.
- Attach a trigger to either the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables (probably not possible) or their native underlying counterparts. Write the trigger code to insert rows into a history/logging table, or write to a log.

Comment: I understand this, but if I have a column_name='id' and it is renamed to column_name='uuid' how will I know that it was renamed but not dropped and uuid column created?

Comment: @McAngujo I do not know a standard way to implement the monitoring you seek. See the section I added to my Answer.